# How do i display an image(AWS) in same page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I need to display an image in jhipster angularjs application(In same Page). The image is rendered from AWS server- so, i have got only document path.

Generally if i give that doc path, it will redirect to chrome to display that image. But, in my case, i need to display in the same screen.

How to achieve this in angularjs?

Note: Document Path: 
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images.iloads.in/Saas_Testing%2FVehicle_1508824497164.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `img` tag to display an image in the browser.

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images.iloads.in/Saas_Testing%2FVehicle_1508824497164.jpeg">
```

If you use AngularJS, change `src` to [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) so that the given value binds to a scope variable.